# Do the Heisenberg uncertainty principle and quantum decoherence relate in some way?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, decoherence, interpretations

Up until now I assumed (in simple words) that a qubit collapses because of the heisenberg uncertainty principle, meaning that we can not measure a qubit without changing it state.
But now I've read about the concept of quantum decoherence that describes why a qubit collapses after measuring it.

So my question is do the heisenberg uncertainty principle and quantum decoherence relate in some way?
If so, is my assumption about the heisenberg uncertainty principle right, or is it much more complex?

Comment: can you add where you read about "quantum decoherence describing why a qubit collapses after measuring it"? Are you referring to Zurek-like arguments or something else?